# Password hashing with salt and getting different hash and different salt any times

Tags: python, bcrypt

I used `bcrypt` and can't saving hash and salt for checking password any times because my salt and hash changed any times.
How I can fix my function to hashing and checking password with `bcrypt`?

My try:

```
import bcrypt

def password_hasher(password):
    pwd = password.encode()
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(pwd, salt)
    return hashed
```

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen. If you want to _compare_ a plain text password to a hash, _use the compare method_.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is generating a new salt every time you call `password_hasher`, which means you will get a different hash every time you hash the same password. This is expected behavior with bcrypt and it's one of its features that helps in adding security. Each time a password is hashed with a new salt, the resulting hash will be different, even if the password is the same.

To verify a password against a previously hashed version, you don't need to store the salt separately. This is because bcrypt hashes include the salt as part of the resulting hash string. Thus, you only need to store the hash.

Modified version of your code:

```py
import bcrypt

def password_hasher(password: str) -> bytes:
    pwd = password.encode()
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(pwd, salt)
    return hashed

def check_password(password: str, hashed_password: bytes) -> bool:
    pwd = password.encode()
    return bcrypt.checkpw(pwd, hashed_password)
```

Usage:

```py
# Hash a new password
hashed_pw = password_hasher("my_password")

# Check the password against the hashed version
is_valid = check_password("my_password", hashed_pw)
print(is_valid)  # This should print True if the password matches
```